# How can I know when an another application was closed and start any service on android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying copy files from another application whenever it is close to have a backup. How can I get some like a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) when the application was closed? This another application is from Play Store, so I can't modify them.

I'm open to suggestions, even requiring root.
Thanks!

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "when the application was closed" means, since applications are not really "closed" on Android.

Comment: Assuming I'm using any application (App 1), I close it, then the activity it is destroyed (onDestroy). At this point my application (App 2) does something, for example opens a notification to "the App 1 was closed." How do I know that the App 1 has been closed?

Comment: "I close it, then the activity it is destroyed (onDestroy)" -- I assume that by "I close it", you mean what Android users would refer to as "I press the system BACK button". Please note that pressing BACK does not necessarily destroy an activity, and pressing BACK has no default impact on the application overall. Plus, there are plenty of ways that users navigate their device that do not involve BACK (e.g., HOME, RECENTS, notifications).

Comment: I know this, i will really destroy the application, no matter how. I just need any that tells me "the activity X of the application Y was destroyed", like a broadcastreceiver.